# How to display responded page by server using GET request in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

```
function regCall(token){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        headers: {
            'x-auth': token
        }
    });
}
```

This is my ajax GET request I want to display the given url in html.
The below is the whole snippet with my login logic.

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
$('#login').submit((e)=>{
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'http://localhost:3000/login/users',
    data: {
      email: $('#email').val(),
      password: $('#password').val()
    },
    success: function(data, status, req){
      // alert(req.getResponseHeader('x-auth'));
      localStorage.setItem('t',req.getResponseHeader('x-auth'));
      var token = localStorage.getItem('t');
      regCall(token);
      // window.location.href = '/';

    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
      // alert(req.getResponseHeader('x-auth'));
      localStorage.setItem('t',req.getResponseHeader('x-auth'));
      alert('Invalid email and password');
      window.location.href = '/login';
    }
   });
  e.preventDefault();
 });
})
```

This is the whole code of snippet.

Answer (score 2):

extract response data from SUCCESS function:

```
function regCall(token){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        headers: {
            'x-auth': token
        },
        success: function(data){
            //targetElement should be replaced by the ID of target element
            $("#targetElement").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: targetElement should be replaced by the **ID** of element you want to insert data. you may use $("body") instead to insert data into body directly. @maheshmaharana

Comment: The new problem is arised when I reload the page then again login page is rendered any solution?

Comment: The problem is not from ajax, check the login logic in `http://localhost:3000` directly and check if it works on refresh?

Comment: Sir please check the post I have edited with login logic.

Comment: SUCCESS and ERROR not means the success login or failed login. It is success of ajax operation. You have to handle localStorage in login page not in the ajax `success` . Similary the ajax error happens in few cases as well as server problem or programming errors and is not related to invalid username and password. @mah

Comment: I suggest posting a new question about login logic to attract more answers.@maheshmaharana

Answer (score 0):

```
By using the success callback function you can display the response content on the HTML place

**First method:**

function regCall(token){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        headers: {
            'x-auth': token
        },
        success: function(responseData){
           $("#div or class Id").html(responseData);
        }

    });
}


**Second method:**

function regCall(token){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        headers: {
            'x-auth': token
        }
    }).done(function(responseData){
     $("#div or class Id").html(responseData);
   });
}

**NOTE:**
Make sure you are having the jQuery script
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The new problem is arised when I reload the page then again login page is rendered any solution?

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in more detail? Upload the code snippet

Comment: Use the session to maintain the state of login user.When you reload/refresh the page check for the session if it exists redirect it to specific page.

Comment: How to do it please elaborate sir?

Comment: Use the cookie and set the cookie when the success function called.Check the cookie on onLoad function if you get the cookie then redirect to specific page otherwise redirect to the same page     .  document.cookie = 'username=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
   document.cookie = "username="+username; I hope this might help you.